# Program crashes at printArray

Tags: c

For some reason printArray crashes the program. It's supposed to calculate flow rate with 15 user defined values for diameter in a 2 dimensional array, then generates a table.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    float q, a, d, v, array[5][3];
    int rows, columns;

    printf("Enter: ");
    scanf("%f",&v);

    for (rows = 0; rows < 5; rows++ )
    {
    for ( columns = 0; columns < 3; columns++)
    {
        printf("Enter value for %d, %d",rows,columns);
        scanf("%d",&array[rows][columns]);
    }
    }
    printArray(array[5][3], v);

}

void printArray(float myArray[][3], float v)
{
    int i, rows, columns;
    float q, a;

    for (rows = 0; rows < 5; rows++ )
    {
    for ( columns = 0; columns < 3; columns++)
    {
        a=(3.14*(myArray[rows][columns]*myArray[rows][columns]))/4;
        q=a*v;
        printf("Diameter: %f Flow rate: %f\n",myArray[rows][columns],q);
    }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: This is no standard compliant C code. `printArray` is undeclared at first use. Compiler warnings exist for a reason and not just to print some fancy text.

Answer (score 1):

```
printArray(array[5][3], v);
```

`array[5][3]` means the element in the 6th row and 4th column. There are two obvious problems here:

- The array doesn't have 6 rows and 4 columns.
- The function expects you to pass (a pointer to) the entire array, not just one element of it.

Change it to:

```
printArray(array, v);
```

Comment: Okay thanks that fixes the crash. Now `printf("Diameter: %f Flow rate: %f\n",myArray[rows][columns],q);` give 0 for each loop. I get that you say the array doesn't have 6 rows and 4 columns but I'm not sure how to fix the problem.

Comment: @UnEntitled Your `scanf` for entering the values in the array is wrong, you should be using `%f` just like you are to get `v`.